# MATLAB: Why do I get a complex number using acos?

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, inverse

Let `K=5`, while `alpha = 1:0.5:10`.

My code is:

```
cos_theta_0 = -1./(2.*alpha)+sqrt(1.+1./(4.*alpha.^2));
theta_0 = acos(cos_theta_0);

 for h = 1:(K-2)
     cos_theta(h,:)= cos_theta_0 - h.*log(2);
     theta(h,:)= acos(cos_theta(h,:));
 end
```

Why do I get back the variable `theta` as a `complex double`?

Comment: What is the *actual* value of `alpha`.

Comment: Because, as Matlab's good documentation tells you, you have given `acos` an argument outside `[-1,1]` ?

Comment: `alpha` is an array made up of 19 value from 1 to 10 with a 0.5 -step @Suever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cos` function looks like this:

[image: Plot of sine and cosine] 
Image Source: [Wikipedia, Trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)

As you can clearly see, the cosine *never* goes above `1` or below `-1`. You are working with the [`acos`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/acos.html), which is the inverse function of the cosine. You basically ask the question: "What value for `x` makes `cos(x)` return my given `y` value?"

Now, for `h=3`, your code creates `cos_theta`'s which are *below* `-1`. As you can see from the graph, it is *not* possible to reach such values with real numbers. However, the cosine of a complex number *can* reach values above `1` and below `-1`. MATLAB correctly recognizes that no real solution exists, but complex solutions do - so it returns complex angles as a result. For `h=1` and `h=2`, the `cos_theta`'s behave nicely and are smaller than `-1`, so the results are real.

**PS:** For-loops are bad/slow. You can drop this one by making `h` a column vector instead of a row vector (by transposing it using `.'`), and then using either `bsxfun` (in "old" MATLAB versions) or use the built-in broadcasting in R2016 or newer.

```
h = (1:K-2).';
cos_theta = bsxfun(@minus, cos_theta_0 , h*log(2));    % For older than R2016
cos_theta = cos_theta_0 - h*log(2);                    % For newer than R2016 
theta = acos(cos_theta);
```